How to copy selected data through to the last column of the same row?
I have been trying out several attempts to copy   data from a set range to the last column of teh same row but had no luck other than doing the CTRL to the Right way. I wanted to figure out a way where i can do it alternativly.
this is my current working code - i want to learn how to properly use a lastcolumn portion to select.
    Range("B2:D2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False


'here is the part i was trying withe a LastColumn Range but failed miserably in my attempt.
 
Dim LastColumn As Long
LastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'other parts to perform'

Range("B2:" & LastColumn &"2").Select  ' here is where i keep getting the debug issue

'Resource for last Column:
'- https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/last-row-column-vba/


I don't really see a question in your post. I suggest you learn about VBA's debugging features. For example, watchpoints let you see values assigned to variables. That helps to determine if what is assigned matches your understanding of how a statement works. Good luck

Ignoring the use of ActiveSheet rather than specifying the sheet - there's nothing really wrong with the LastColumn line. But I notice you're attempting to Range().Select from row 2, but the LastColumn is scanning row 1..? Try changing the 1 to 2?
